# Knockout doesn't apply binding for given viewmodel

Tags: knockout.js, knockout-mapping-plugin

Could someone explain me why this works

```
    self.test("some data");
    <span data-bind="text:test"></span>
```

and this not work

```
    self.test(ko.mapping.fromJS({ complex: "object"}));
    <span data-bind="text:test.complex"></span>
```

Comment: use test().complex in the second binding

Comment: cannot read property complex or null

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`test` is an observable, so you have to unwrap it to access the internal properties.

```
self.test(ko.mapping.fromJS({ complex: "object"}));
<span data-bind="text:test().complex"></span>
```

Comment: why should I unwrap observable in knockout binding? I will have need in it if I'll do some operations like != or > ...

Comment: @user2586558 Unwrapping `test` allows you to access the underlying value, which is an object containing one property - `complex`. In knockout, in order to access the underlying value, you always have to unwrap observables.

Comment: something bad with scripts.cant understand. all bindings except this works normally.thanks.

Comment: @user2586558 I'm not sure if that means it worked for you or not, but if so, please make sure you mark the answer as accepted.

Comment: The answer is correct. test is an observable, which is a function. The property 'complex' is not set on this function, so test.complex doesn't work. executing test by doing `test()` gives the actual VALUE of the observable, on which the property complex is set. so test().complex will work.

Just follow this simple rule: in your bindings, you can ONLY omit the () on the last part of the object. For example data-bind="text: a", data-bind="text: a().b", data-bind="text: a().b().c". the observable just helps with automatic UI updates, sometimes you need the ACTUAL VALUE inside the observable.